# ec- vs ex- What is the difference

Tags: etymology, prefixes

Both the prefix means the same thing eccentric - outer center vs external - outer
all in all they means the same then what is the difference here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the information at the link below, they both mean the same: 'outside' - however the 'ex' version is used before vowels, and the 'ec' version, before consonants.

The origins are also different - which is why they are different, in English - the ex is from Latin and Greek, the ec from Greek - so that's another reason for the seeming 'lack of logic' here - that they came from different countries and languages originally.

Eccentric is a Greek loan word, so it uses ec.

Eg:

- Exit (the way to outside)
- Ectopic (outside the womb)
- Eccentric (outside the norm)

http://wordinfo.info/unit/786/s:acentric

Please see Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment below for a much more erudite and accurate description of how ec and ex are affected by surrounding letters.

Comment: You’re getting things conflated a bit here (or rather, Wordinfo is). In **Greek**, _ec-_ (or _ek-_) is used before consonants generally, and _ex-_ (or _eks-_) before vowels. In **Latin**, however, _ex-_ is used before vowels as well as /s/ and unvoiced plosives /p t k/, while before other consonants the shorter form _e-_ is used. _Ec-_ is only used (1) in Greek loan words, like _eccentricus_, and (2) before /f/, and even there the /k/ assimilates to the /f/, giving /fː/ (written _ff_).

Comment: In have put another mention of Latin and Greek back in as I feel this is part of the point of my answer.